# Adding reCAPTCHA v2 into my PHP file

Tags: php, html, captcha, recaptcha

The PHP problem has been solved. Here are the HTML and PHP codes that I'm using:

**contact_form.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Contact Form</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contact-form">
        <h3>Send me your message</h3>
        <form action="app/contact.php" method="POST">
            <div class="text-fields">
                <span>Full Name *:</span>
                <input name="full_name" type="text" class="text" value="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="text-fields">
                <span>E-mail *:</span>
                <input name="email" type="text" class="text" value="user@domain.com">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
                <div class="subject-field">
                <span>Subject *:</span>
                <input name="subject" type="text" class="text" value="Your Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="message-field">
                <span>Message *:</span>
                <textarea name="message"> </textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE-KEY-HERE"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the updated PHP. With this I'm also getting my From field as I wanted which is "Sender Name ".

**contact_form.php:**

```
<?php
    $full_name;$email;$subject;$message;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['full_name'])){
            $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
        }if(isset($_POST['email'])){
            $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
            $subject=$_POST['subject'];
        }if(isset($_POST['message'])){
            $message=$_POST['message'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
            $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
            echo 'Check the reCAPTCHA box.';
            exit;
        }
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET-KEY-HERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
            echo 'You are a robot!';
        }else
        {
            $to = "me@domain.com";
            $from = $full_name . ' <'.$email.'>';
            $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
            mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo 'Your message has been sent!';
        }
?>
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: See the documentation: https://github.com/google/recaptcha#usage

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['full_name']) && isset($_POST['full_name']) ){
        $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; 
         $email = $_POST['email'];
         $from_name_email = $full_name . '<'.$email.'>';
     }
     if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
     }
    if(isset($_POST['message'])){
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }
     }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $to = "my@email.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $from_name_email . "\r\n";
    }
    if(!$captcha){
        echo 'Please check the the captcha form.';
        exit;
    }
    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR SECRET KEY GOES HERE&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if($response.success==false)
            {
              echo 'You are spammer!';
            }else
            {
        mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "Your message has been sent! Thank you.";
            }  
    ?>
```

Comment: This code still contains the nonsensical fragment `$response.success==false`. This does nothing meaningful.

Comment: it says you are a spammer if captha doesn´t work ok ??

Comment: No, actually, it won't. `$response.success` appends the string "success" to `$response`; the result of that operation will never be false.

Comment: And how it would work fine ? Thank you a lot and sorry for my mistake

Comment: $response['success'] might work if parsed as json. Why is this not answered?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it work for me:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['full_name']) && isset($_POST['full_name']) ){
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name']; 
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $from_name_email = $full_name . '<'.$email.'>';
 }
 if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 }
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}
 }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $to = "my@email.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from_name_email . "\r\n";
}
if(!$captcha){
    echo 'Please check the the captcha form.';
    exit;
}
//change is here
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=USE PRIVATE KEY HERE&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        //change is here
        $response = json_decode($response);
        //change is here
        if($response->success==false)
        {
          echo 'You are spammer!';
        }else
        {
    mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo "Your message has been sent! Thank you.";
        }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 if(!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) || empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        echo 'reCAPTHCA verification failed, please try again.';
    } else {
        $secret = 'google_secret_key';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response);

        if($response->success) {
            // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            echo 'Successful .';
        } else {
            // Your code here to handle a successful verification
            echo 'reCAPTHCA verification failed, please try again.';
        }
    }
```